# Is there a way to enable SSL for the RabbitMQ management console on Bitnami?

Tags: rabbitmq, bitnami

While the RabbitMQ documentation clearly guides the way to enable SSL for the management console https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#single-listener-https
I could not find a way to do this for the bitnami image: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq

Is there a way to enable SSL for the management console as well with the Bitnami image?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the env vars explained [here](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq#management-server-configuration)